# Is there an idiomatic way to have a generic over T, &T, Box<T>, Arc<T>, and so forth, where T implements some trait R?

Tags: generics, rust

Let's say you have a structure that you want to be a generic over time type `T`, so long as that type implements some trait `R`.  That's pretty trivial:

```rust
trait R {
    fn func_a(&self);
    fn func_b(&mut self);
}
struct A;
impl R for A {
    fn func_a(&self) {}
    fn func_b(&mut self) {}
}
struct B<T>(T) where T: R;

fn main() {
    let _ = B(A);
    // let _ = B(&A); // Error: the trait `R` is not implemented for `&A`
}
```

But this gets more complicated if you want `B` to also accept references (`&A`) or smart pointers (`Box<A>`, `Arc<A>`, etc...)  One approach is to `impl R` for references specific smart pointers.  For example,

```rust
impl R for &A { /*...*/ }
impl R for Box<A> { /*...*/ }
// etc...
```

While this approach seems simple, it doesn't work when `R` has methods that take a `&mut self` because of Rust's mutability rules.  And, even if all `R`'s methods *do* take a `&self`, the set of smart pointers that can be used are limited to those you explicity put in implementations for, and your code is littered with proxy implementations.

The alternative approach is to use the `Deref` trait.  This works for all the smart pointers at once, but no longer works for the simple owned value.  Of course, if you want the resulting `B` to have a `'static` lifetime, it's trivial to create a new `Box`, but this also means an unnecessary memory allocation.

```rust
struct B<T>(T) where T: Deref, T::Target: R;
fn main() {
    // let _ = B(A); // Error: the trait bound `A: Deref` is not satisfied
    let _ = B(&A);
    let _ = B(Box::new(A));
}
```

Finally, we have the `Borrow` trait.  Becuase the standard library includes a blanket `impl Borrow<T> for T`, as well as the smart pointers, but this now becomes rather awkward to use.  Our structure `B` needs to have a `PhantomData<U>`, and our uses need type annotations or they don't compile.

```rust
struct B<T, U>(T, PhantomData<U>) where T: Borrow<U>, U: R;
fn main() {
    let _ = B::<&A, A>(&A, Default::default());
    let _ = B::<Box<A>, A>(Box::new(A), Default::default());
    let _ = B(A, Default::default());
}
```

Of these options, using the `Deref` trait seems to the cleanest.  You can even make it work with an owned value by creating a trivial wrapper type like this `OwnedCell`.

```rust
struct B<T>(T) where T: Deref, T::Target: R;
struct OwnedCell<T>(T);
impl<T> Deref for OwnedCell<T> {
    type Target = T;
    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        &self.0
    }
}
fn main() {
    let _ = B(&A);
    let _ = B(Box::new(A));
    let _ = B(OwnedCell(A));
}
```

However, the fact that there doesn't seem to be anything like `OwnedCell` in the standard library makes me think I might be missing something here.  What's the right way to do this?

Comment: After thinking about this a bit, I think `Borrow` is the right approach here. `Deref` is intended to be used by smart pointers to support syntactic sugar (auto deref). `Borrow` is a better semantic fit for the requirement here. The `PhantomData` detail can be hidden behind a private field.